# send multiple ajax call to a same file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a big table and my idea to optimize my program is to get the information one by one and update the table as the information arrives.

To do that I am using an ajax call to a php file which collect the data from the database. I am trying to send and receive the data one by one:

```
 for (var i = depF; i <= depT; i++) {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "../../php_includes/reports/InventoryReportPage.php?date=" + arguments[0] + "&depF=" + i + "&depT=" + i + "&subT=" + subT + "&subF=" + subF + "&catT=" + catT
                + "&catF=" + catF + "&Tar=" + Tar, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        console.log("sent ajax");
    }
```

this code will correctly send 2 ajax calls (in the browser I can see two "sent ajax"). However in the receiver:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
        {
            console.log("recieved");
            if (xmlhttp.responseText) {
                var table = document.getElementById("inventoryReport");
                table.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
```

I only see one return value. Any idea if I am even allowed to use ajax calls like this?

The whole function:

```
var isClicked = false;
function onClick(date, depF, depT, subF, subT, catT, catF, Tar) {
//alert(date+ depF+ depT+ subF+ subT+ catT+ catF+ Tar)
// return null;
if (!isClicked) {
    console.log("in the function");
    var clicked = arguments[0];
    isClicked = true;
    var div = clicked + "apDiv";
    var browserSupport = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1) || ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1));
    if (browserSupport) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
    if (!xmlhttp) {
        alert("your browser doens't supposrt XMLHTTP " + navigator.userAgent);
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
        {
            console.log("recieved: "+xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (xmlhttp.responseText) {
                var table = document.getElementById("inventoryReport");
                table.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = depF; i <= depT; i++) {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "../../php_includes/reports/InventoryReportPage.php?date=" + arguments[0] + "&depF=" + arguments[1] + "&depT=" + arguments[2] + "&subT=" + subT + "&subF=" + subF + "&catT=" + catT
                + "&catF=" + catF + "&Tar=" + Tar, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        console.log("sent the ajax");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can fiddle around and make this work, or you can use jQuery, and it makes ajax calls and handlers simple to work with.

Comment: you need to create a xmlhttp object with "new"

Comment: I am trying to fix this code. One more thing I realized is: if I look at my network I see the other request status is canceled. Is this something I need to configure in the server?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you're having problems with the closure (or non-closure) of your calls, have you checked with devTools ? see the network tab (f12 on firefox/chrome/ie) and check if there are 2 requests.

can you add your xmlhttp object declaration ?

Comment: There are multiple requests however all of them except the last one are cancelled!!

Comment: I thinks it's because you're using the same object for the requests, try declaring the xmlhttp object inside your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code don't work as you expect is that you basically overwrite the requests you are doing. You can try something like this:

```
var reqs = [];

for (var i = depF; i <= depT; i++) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "/", true);
      xmlhttp.send();

      reqs.push(xmlhttp);
}

reqs.forEach(function(req) {
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200)
        {
            console.log("recieved");
            if (req.responseText) {
                var table = document.getElementById("inventoryReport");
                table.innerHTML += req.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
})
```